# Flutter app throws Xcode error in debugger

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

So, when I try to debug the app, it gives me this error:

```
Error (Xcode): Target debug_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Binary /Users/ayxan/nba_app_api/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flutter.framework/Flutter does not exist, cannot thin
```

I tried everything, but no solution helps me.